# Index 0 out of range [0...0]

Tags: android, mysql, json

I am getting this in my Json method.
I am trying to get information from my server and mysql database and then display it in my username text view.
This is my Json Method. It throws the index out of range error.

```
 private void showJSON(String response) {
    String username = "";

    try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
        JSONArray result = jsonObject.getJSONArray(Constantss.JSON_ARRAY);
        JSONObject profileData = result.getJSONObject(0);
        username = profileData.getString(Constantss.USERNAME);

        System.out.println("first" + username);


    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }

    usernameView.setText(username);
    System.out.println("second" + username);

}
```

Probably not needed but this is how I am getting my data, It works fine I am able to retrieve the Id and also run the php code to give me the username.

```
 private void getData() {
    class lata extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider(
                    getApplicationContext(), //Context
                    "us-east--------------",   //Identity Pool ID
                    Regions.US_EAST_1 // Region
                    //Now we retrieve
            );

//        return null;
            String identityID = credentialsProvider.getIdentityId();
            Log.d("LogTag", "my ID is" + identityID);
            String id = identityID;
            String userid = identityID;

            System.out.println("Id is" + identityID);
            System.out.println("Id tis" + id);
            String url = Constantss.PROFILE_URL + identityID;
            StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    showJSON(response);
                }
            },
                    new Response.ErrorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                            Toast.makeText(Profile.this, error.getMessage().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        }
                    });
            RequestQueue requestQueue =     Volley.newRequestQueue(Profile.this);
            requestQueue.add(stringRequest);


            return identityID;
        }


    }
    lata pasta = new lata();
    pasta.execute();
}
```

Comment: This is all Java code. Where does `mysqli` factor in?

Comment: I am using php to and Mysqli to retrieve the information.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the length of your array is 0. Please check it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try verifying the response var in

`private void showJSON(String response) {`

Is not empty

Answer (score 0):

Use Gson to decode the json will be much more convenient than the way you did , and obviously the JSONArray result's length is 0